# How to calculate the z-score for the number of times an event occurs?

Tags: statistics

I have a set of known data, assumed to be correct, and a set of new data that I want to check for falsification before merging it into known data. The data is essentially the probability of an event occurring (the overall data measures 4 of these events). If one of the 4 events has a z-score above a certain value it's tagged as potentially falsified and if it's above a higher value again it's rejected. For the cases where the known data might be incorrect, the tagged and rejected submissions are logged for human review.

To do this, I'm trying to calculate the z-score but I'm having trouble deriving the denominator or the equation.

$$
Z = {X - E(X) \over \sigma}
$$
$$
Z = {X - E(X) \over \sqrt{Var(X)}}
$$
$$
Z = {X - E(X) \over \sqrt{E[X^2] - (E[X])^2}}
$$
I can then substitute in value for the numerator:
$$
Z = {{sampleEvent \over sampleOverall} - {knownEvent \over knownOverall} \over \sqrt{E[X^2] - (E[X])^2}}
$$
But unfortunately I don't understand how to expand the denominator. Could anyone shed shome light on this?